# Blog - sometimes you can comment other times you cannot - why?

Tags: discussion

Why is the blog of Stack Exchange different on various posts? For instance, this blog post allows comments:
http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/Stack-Spotlight-Bethany-Marzewski/

But this one doesn't:
http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/why-stack-overflow-is-a-good-workplace-for-women/

Why not allow commenting in all blog entries?

Comment: And you cannot comment on the new blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/11/How-We-Talk-About-Diversity-at-Stack-Overflow/?cb=1